# When attempting to run a script, I recieve the message "ls: cannot access '*.bash_history': No such file or directory"

Tags: 16.04, scripts, darktable

I have been attempting to make custom base curves in darktable using the following guide

https://web.archive.org/web/20170701041347/http://weeklyedit.com/basecurves/

and also using the replacement script from this location

https://gist.github.com/robertvalik/ee9bc87972e326311cef5f505d44cec3

Once I attempt to run the script I receive the message

```
rm: cannot remove 'basecurve.dat': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'basecurve.fit.dat': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'basecurve.sh': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'dt-curve-tool.bin': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'tonecurve.dat': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'tonecurve.fit.dat': No such file or directory
./script.zsh:5: no matches found: *.bash_history
cat: iso_model_db: No such file or directory
```

for the original script and the message

```
ls: cannot access '*.bash_history': No such file or directory
```

or the replacement script.

I'm basically a beginner in regards to scripting and have struggled through the guide after having previous errors show but this error has got me stumped for several hours.

So if anyone can enlighten me, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I never heard of darktable before, but it looks like an open source version of Lightroom.  I definitely want to check it out, it seems like a great option for LR as I don't think Adobe makes a linux version.

That being said, I'm not familiar with the program, and I just know a little bit about scripting, but the most of errors you're receiving are because the script is trying to delete some files which aren't there.  This leads me to question if you have darktable installed already.  These files are part of darktable and get put in your ~/.config/darktable directory once it's been installed and it needs to be installed before running these scripts.

Also, your .bash_history file is usually found in your home (~) directory, and so maybe you're running the script from the incorrect directory.  Did you try looking at the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LufwQZx01gk. It was at the top of the second link you provided and it looks like he does a better job of walking you through the steps.  I looked at it quickly so I'm not sure if you need your bracketed photos before or after the script.  I would sit down, watch the video once through, then watch it a second time following his steps.  Best of luck.